# How to delete a node from firebase by referring it's child node?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

```
"Subscription" : {
    "1519197182611" : {
      "address" : "Mumbai",
      "dateTime" : "Feb 21, 2018 12:42:57 PM",
      "name" : "ABC",
      "phone" : "1264897809",
      "uIdpId" : "123456"
    },
    "1519197186551" : {
      "address" : "Mumbai",
      "dateTime" : "Feb 21, 2018 12:42:57 PM",
      "name" : "DCF",
      "phone" : "1264897809",
      "uIdpId" : "7897"
    },
    "1519197360198" : {
      "address" : "Mumbai",
      "dateTime" : "Feb 21, 2018 12:45:54 PM",
      "name" : "XYZ",
      "phone" : "1264897809",
      "uIdpId" : "45656"
    }
  }
```

I want to delete the node through whose name is `ABC`.
So how can i proceed further. I got stuck here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
DatabaseReference data = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Subscription");
data.orderByChild("name").equalTo(ABC).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
         @Override
      public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
      for(DataSnapshot data: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
            data.getRef().removeValue();

                  }

            }

        @Override
       public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

               }
          });
```

The snapshot is at child `Subscription`, then you use `orderByChild("name").equalTo(valuehere)` which is the condition that name should be equal to ABC for example.

Then using the for loop you iterate inside the random pushids, `getRef()` will give you the reference of this source location and `removeValue()` will remove the node.

Comment: I want to check whether a nodes exits or not whose name is 'xyz'. what code  should I write??

Comment: @Himanshü change the condition `orderByChild("name").equalTo(XYZ)` and inside of this `public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {`. You can do `if(dataSnapshot.exists()){ //it exists...`